# Snackbar with CoordinatorLayout disable dismiss

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

I am using the support

- FloatingActionButton
- Snackbar
- CoordinatorLayout

I need the **CoordinatorLayout** so that if **SnackBar** is shown the **FloatingActionButton** moves up to make room for the Snackbar. For better understanding check this [video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsLWFucDNlYWEyeW8/components_snackbar_usage_fabdo_002.webm).

I am using SnackBar for double-back to exit the application, but the SnackBar can be dismissed.

Is there a way to disable the dismiss on the SnackBar?

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.press_back_again_to_exit, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snackbar.setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
});
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

View view = snackbar.getView();
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_warning));

snackbar.show();
```

Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
            sothree:umanoPanelHeight="100dp"
            sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

            <!-- Toolbar and main content -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_and_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

                <!-- Your content layout -->
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Sliding up panel layout -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/darker_grey"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>


        <!-- Navigation drawer -->
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:divider="@color/divider_color"
            android:dividerHeight="0.6dp"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/button_drawer_child_selector"
            android:scrollbarSize="0dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**P.S.**

I am aware of [this GitHub library](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar), that has this functionality, but is there a 'native' way to do it?

Comment: I think there is no way

Comment: *I am using SnackBar for double-back to exit the application* - you're going against the platform's UI patterns. SnackBars are for small feedback and not for asking the user for action(like I'm assuming you're trying to do when the user presses back twice)

Comment: @Luksprog I am aware of that, same could be achieved with a Toast or a Crouton, but it's basically the same, SnackBar just looks nicer. I am personally not a fan of double-back to exit, but unfortunately it's not for me to decide.

Comment: Check my answer.....http://stackoverflow.com/a/35576829/1881527

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can alter the duration of Snackbar to be shown. It will be similar to disable dismiss.

```
int     LENGTH_INDEFINITE   Show the Snackbar indefinitely.
```

Check [docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html).

if it does not work
For this then there is only one way, Implement Your custom Snackbar and override `dismiss()` method and in that do nothing. :) As `dismiss()` is a public API.

Comment: Does not work, SnackBar is still dismissable, and stays there forever :)

Comment: [ dismissable or stay forever ] can you explain a bit. This seems to be contradictory ;)

Comment: If I set LENGTH_INDEFINITE the SnackBar doesn't go away after time... (makes sense), but I can still dismiss it (swipe right and it goes away).

Comment: @Marko : check edited answer. I know its a log way but its doable.

Comment: @theJango It's not.. while `Snackbar` is not a `final` class, its only constructor is `private`, effectively making it `final`

Answer (score 11):

Snackbar now has actual support disabling swipe to dismiss using the setBehavior method. The great thing here is that before you would always lose some behaviors which are now preserved. You'll also want to use `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE`

Note that the package moved so you have to import the "new" [Snackbar in the snackbar package](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar).

```
Snackbar.make(view, stringId, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .setBehavior(new NoSwipeBehavior())
    .show();

class NoSwipeBehavior extends BaseTransientBottomBar.Behavior {

    @Override
    public boolean canSwipeDismissView(View child) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer about just using `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` is not sufficient.

It is only non-dismissable when the Snackbar is *no child* of `CoordinatorLayout`. 
When it is a child, you can still swipe away the SnackBar.

What you can do in that case is **listen for the dismiss swipe** and simply re-show the Snackbar.

```java
public void showAnnoyingSnackBar(View root, String text) {
    Snackbar.make(root, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                // recursively call this method again when the snackbar was dismissed through a swipe
                if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_SWIPE) showAnnoyingSnackBar(root, text);
            }
        })
        .show();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that when show() method is called, **SnackbarLayout** is not fully initialised yet.

To lock dissmiss we have to clear behavior after **SnackbarLayout** initialisation.
the best place to do this is for example in **OnPreDrawListener** of **SnackbarLayout**

```
final Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(getView(), "I can't be dissmiss", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snack.show();
    snack.getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            snack.getView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snack.getView().getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in disabling the swipe-sideways-to-dismiss snackbars with the following hack (after calling snackbar.show())

```
((android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
```

Comment: Awsome, I have to try it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This does not work for me. `Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.rootView, "Blah", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT); snackbar.show();((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);`