# How to Disable snackbar swipe to dismis behaviour

Tags: android, swipe-gesture, android-snackbar, snackbar

I want to disable swipe to dismiss behavior of `snackbar` i have tried 
lot of things not worked any for me , any one suggest how can i achieve this, 
Here is what i have tried

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(main_content, getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
        snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
       // textView.setTypeface(fontLight);
        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                apiAccess();
            }
        });


        snackbar.show();
```

This is my snackbar code i have tried two things :

1

```
((android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
```

after `snackbar.show();`  method but didn't worked.

2

```
main_content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = main_content.getLayoutParams();
                        if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
                            ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp).setBehavior(new DisableSwipeBehavior());
                            main_content.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        }
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            main_content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            //noinspection deprecation
                            main_content.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                });

        public class DisableSwipeBehavior extends SwipeDismissBehavior<Snackbar.SnackbarLayout> {
        @Override
        public boolean canSwipeDismissView(@NonNull View view) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In Above code `main_content`  is my CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: so you need to keep it without disabling or only not allow it to disable using swipe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031476/how-to-disable-snackbars-swipe-to-dismiss-behavior

Comment: yes i want to put snackbar visible as it is. don't want to dismiss from swiping left @Charuka

Comment: do you need any other actions in that or only display it? If you only want to display code is less you need to type

Comment: I want only 1 action "RETRY"

Comment: saved my day helped me